# Названия городов во множественном числе

Tags: имена-собственные

Здравствуйте!
Интересно было бы узнать, почему названия некоторых городов употребляются во множественном числе: Канны, Афины, Фивы. Но ведь это русский способ образования множественного числа, откуда же он взялся в иностранных названиях?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

А почему не может быть названия во множественном числе? У нас, правда, оно используется не столько для городов сколько для деревень и посёлков: Городки, Холмики, Малинники, и т.п. Город Афины так и есть во множественном числе, и это множественное число "переведено" на русский буквой "Ы". У названия этого города очень запутанная история, которую лучше меня могут рассказать местные историки. :) В общем, сначало он, по моему, назывался Афина, в честь оной богини. Потом по какой-то причине его название стали писать во множественном числе, но после опять перешли на еденичное, но записи остались... И так, одна Афина превратилась во множество Афин.

Про Фивы не знаю, но предпологаю что тоже похожая история.

Канны - Cannes. Опять множественное число. Значит тоже сохранилось при переводе.

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что в данном случае это не множественное число, а, скорее склонение.

Comment: Склонение чего? Вы имеете в виду что-то вроде "у города Фивы"? А где - в Фиве? Что - Фива? Это не склонение, это название города, во множественном числе.